# Ajax form timing out

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a **PHP page with form** with 100s of fields in it. I'm using **Ajax to fetch content** to each field upon **typing in the data**.

Sometimes, it happens that I get this error:

> net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Presumably because the server fails to respond on time. When that happens, there is an error and Ajax won't work further.

Is there a way I can make the code execute even after the error? So that I can continue trying Ajax again?

**Note**: I'm using plain old **XMLHttpRequest()** request, not jquery functions

Comment: Please post your code - this way there'll less guesswork on what's actually wrong here

Answer (score 2):

In your ajax code try to define the timeout settings to 0 (unlimited):

```
$.ajax({
timeout: 0, //Set your timeout value in milliseconds or 0 for unlimited
```

You can set this value to 3 seconds (3000) and catch the exception with the error function. Like this:

```
error: function(jqXHR, textError, errorThrown) {
    if(textError==="timeout") {  
        alert("Call has timed out"); //Handle the timeout
    } else {
        alert("Unknown error"); //Handle other error type
    }
```

Hope that will help

Comment: I'm not using Jquery, I'm using plain old XMLHttpRequest() , I'll try using timeout with that https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/timeout

Comment: As I understand, adding timeout only dictates for how long the script should wait for response, if there is a failed response, will the script stop working? or will it take the next ajax requests and continue with them? Chrome seems to be cancelling all script execution if an error occurs, is there a way to bypass that from within chrome?

Comment: You can access to the chrome events with this link: chrome://net-internals/#events

To see why it was cancelled

Comment: Try to add an eventListener to the "abort" status. I don't know if it's trigger when chrome cancelled your request.

var xhr= new XMLHttpRequest(); 
xhr.addEventListener("abort",abortProblem)

function abortProblem(event){}

Comment: From documentation - `The default value is 0, which means there is no timeout`

Answer (score -1):

You can use this function to catch all kind of errors you can get in ajax :

```
$.ajax({
    url: "your_url",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    timeout: 5000, /* timeout in milliseconds */
    success: function(response) { alert(response); },
    error: function(jqXHR, exception) {
        if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
            return ('Not connected.\nPlease verify your network connection.');
        } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
            return ('The requested page not found. [404]');
        } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
            return ('Internal Server Error [500].');
        } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
            return ('Requested JSON parse failed.');
        } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
            return ('Time out error.');
        } else if (exception === 'abort') {
            return ('Ajax request aborted.');
        } else {
            return ('Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
        }
    }
});​
```